# Passing NSE to dplyr's filter

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

```
library(dplyr)

specials <- names(mtcars)[1:2]
specials[1]

i=1
```

setup is complete, 
this works...

```
mtcars %>%
  select_(specials[i], ~gear, ~carb)
```

why does the nse fail on adding the filter?

```
mtcars %>%
  select_(specials[i], ~gear, ~carb) %>%
  filter_(specials[i] == 21.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need the `interp`

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
      select_(specials[i], ~gear, ~carb) %>% 
      filter_(interp(~nm == 21.4, nm = as.name(specials[1])))
#  mpg gear carb
#1 21.4    3    1
#2 21.4    4    2
```

Comment: To elaborate on the answer, `special[i]`  has the value "mpg" and `"mpg" == 21.4` is not true. Hence, the failure. `filter_` evaluates boolean expressions, so we have to construct an expression that uses `mpg` as a column-name. `lazyeval::interp` provides a way to plug values into expressions.